# preg_replace data between html tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to do a preg_replace matching the data in between the html tags.

this pattern works great, but I don't know how to get the match string.

```
preg_replace("/(?<=>)[^><]+?(?=<)/", "$1",$string);
```

not knowing much about regex, I'd assume that $1 would return the match, but it doesn't. now this pattern (above) can remove all data between html tags if i

```
preg_replace("/(?<=>)[^><]+?(?=<)/", "",$string);
```

my main goal is to have a line where i can put the returned match thru a function like

```
preg_replace("/(?<=>)[^><]+?(?=<)/", string_function("$1"),$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [preg_replace_callback](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to apply a custom function.

Also preg_replace won't return anything I think you need preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

> not knowing much about regex, I'd assume that $1 would return the match, but it doesn't.

Use `"$0"`. You're not capturing any groups, so group 1 will not exist (meaning `$1` will not refer to anything). See the description of the `replacement` parameter in the [`preg_replace()` docs](http://php.net/preg-replace) for more about `$0` and friends.

> my main goal is to have a line where i can put the returned match thru a function like

To run a function on the matched string(s), you should use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead. The method signature is as follows:

> `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )`

If you pass in the `matches` parameter, then it will get filled with the resulting matches.

E.g.:

```
preg_match("/(?<=>)[^><]+?(?=<)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

`$matches` should contain the result you want.